# Use Macbook as bluetooth peripheral and send data to it in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to write an integer value to my Macbook Air using CoreBluetooth. A user would slide a slider on the phone screen, and the updates would get sent to a serial terminal on the Macbook in near-real time.

The issue is that when I scan for all devices, my iPhone only occasionally detects the macbook (i.e. sometimes 10 times in a minute, sometimes only 1 or 2).

Trying to connect to the Macbook peripheral produces no clear result. Even when storing the macbook as a peripheral in an array and then attempting to connect through those means fails.

I'd like to write a value to the Macbook but I'd have no idea where to read it from. I also have to write a characteristic but I'm not sure what to define the characteristic as, and how to subscribe to it on the Macbook side.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to connect to it? Or at least only write data to it reliably, without connecting? Below is my code attempt so far. I print any peripheral when found, I've tried storing it in a variable outside the function and connecting to that, as well as directly connecting to the peripheral, and nothing happens.

```
var peripherals = [CBPeripheral]()
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print(peripheral)
        peripherals.append(peripheral)
        central.retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers(macbookIdentifiers)
        //central.connectPeripheral(peripherals[0], options: nil)
        central.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Your code for connecting looks correct (aside from the unnecessary `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers` which I assume is part of your testing). Once you connect you would discover the service that your Mac app is offering, discover the caharateristic of the service and then issue write commands to that characteristic. On the Mac side you will get delegate callbacks when your app writes a value.  Do you have corresponding code on the Mac that is advertising a peripheral?

Comment: No I don't. How could I go about doing this? I just want a simple service that prints the values the iPhone is sending on the Mac's side.

Comment: You need to applications to achieve what you want; an app in iOS to connect to a peripheral and send a value and an app on OS X to act as a peripheral, advertise a service for the iOS app to find and receive the values.

Comment: Are there any guides for running it on the mac side? I haven't been finding much for it :-/

Comment: The frameworks are basically the same. You need to create an instance of CBPeripheralManager and a CBMutablePeripheral. Check the Core Bluetooth programming guide